# JavaScript Variable Name Regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a regex that will replace all invalid characters in a JavaScript variable name with underscores (in Java).

What I'm wanting to do is:

```
String jsVarName = "1inva>idName".replaceAll("[a-zA-Z_$][0-9a-zA-Z_$]", "_");
```

and end up with a variable named `_inva_idName`.

What I'm struggling to do is figure out how to make the first character different to the others.

`[a-zA-Z_$][0-9a-zA-Z_$]` are the characters I want, but I cant figure out to hook them into the correct syntax. I know JS var names can be full unicode, but I only care about about ASCII.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/valid-characters-for-javascript-variable-names

Comment: since the title is somewhat confusing, note that a javascript variable name can contain far more charactesr than just `0-9a-zA-Z_$`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String jsVarName = "1inva>idName".replaceAll("^[^a-zA-Z_$]|[^0-9a-zA-Z_$]", "_");
```

Note that since `\w` is `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`, it can be simplified:

```
String jsVarName = "1inva>idName".replaceAll("^[^a-zA-Z_$]|[^\\w$]", "_")
```

`^[^a-zA-Z_$]` matches anything that is not `[a-zA-Z_$]` and appears at the beginning of the line. `|` is OR. `[^0-9a-zA-Z_$]` matches anything that is not `[0-9a-zA-Z_$]`.

See [regex tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) for more info.

Comment: Oh you were talking in relation with my answer, sorry I'm a little slow atm. I thought the character class after `|` would also match the beginning of the string without negating the `^` but apparently it works without it.

Comment: Oh damn, I didn't realize the first group is contained in the second group. +1 your answer is pretty cleaner.